# KDB how to create a vector of length n

Tags: kdb

I am trying to add a date column to a table, so I want to do an update, adding today's date to each row.

```
http://www.timestored.com/b/forums/topic/add-a-column-to-a-table-kdb/
```

Following that link I would just update it, but I can't find out how to create a vector of length count table filled with today's date. 
Sounds so simple, I just cant find the way to do this, so appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'take' function `#`. E.g.

```
q)length:10
q)length#.z.d
2017.04.27 2017.04.27 2017.04.27 2017.04.27 2017.04.27 2017.04.27 2017.04.27 2017.04.27 2017.04.27 2017.04.27
```

Although you could probably just do a regular update, E.g.

```
q)t
s   p
-----
IBM 1
IBM 1
IBM 1
q)update dt:.z.d from t
s   p dt
----------------
IBM 1 2017.04.27
IBM 1 2017.04.27
IBM 1 2017.04.27
```

Comment: I agree with @james-little, simply use the `update dt:.z.d from t` method; no need to cut vectors and append.

Answer (score 3):

As James mentioned, if you update/generate a column in a table using an atom then kdb will automatically turn the atom into a vector of the required length.

```
q)tab:([] col1:`a`b`c;col2:1 2 3)
q)update date:.z.d from tab
col1 col2 date
--------------------
a    1    2017.04.27
b    2    2017.04.27
c    3    2017.04.27
```

This also occurs with a flip

```
q)flip (1 2 3;`a)
1 `a
2 `a
3 `a
```

However for strings or other nested structures this will not happen. In this case you have to manually generate the vector

```
q)update str:count[i]#enlist "hello" from tab
col1 col2 str
-----------------
a    1    "hello"
b    2    "hello"
c    3    "hello"
```